# ORDER BY column TIMEC or expression not in result table?

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange, db2-400

So I've got 2 queries:

**Query 1:**

```
SELECT        
a.memno, 
a.name, 
a.addr1, 
a.addr2, 
a.city, 
a.state, 
a.zip, 
a.sex, 
a.lname, 
a.ssan, 
b.addr1 AS old_addr1, 
b.addr2 AS old_addr2, 
b.city AS old_city, 
b.state AS old_state, 
b.zip AS old_zip

FROM            LIB1.TABLE1 a, LIB2.TABLE2 b

WHERE        (a.memno = b.memno) AND 

(b.groupid = 'P2') AND 
(b.type = 'B') AND 
(b.datec = 20131203) AND 
(a.addr1 <> b.addr1) AND 
(a.addr2 <> b.addr2) AND 
(a.city <> b.city) AND 
(a.state <> b.state) AND 
(a.zip <> b.zip)

ORDER BY b.timec DESC
```

*Returns 1 record.*

**Query 2:**

```
SELECT        
a.memno, 
a.name, 
a.addr1, 
a.addr2, 
a.city, 
a.state, 
a.zip, 
a.sex, 
a.lname, 
a.ssan, 
b.addr1 AS old_addr1, 
b.addr2 AS old_addr2, 
b.city AS old_city, 
b.state AS old_state, 
b.zip AS old_zip

FROM            LIB2.TABLE1 a, LIB2.TABLE2 b

WHERE        (a.memno = b.memno) AND 
(b.groupid = 'N2') AND 
(b.type = 'B') AND 
(b.datec = 20131203) AND 
(a.addr1 <> b.addr1) AND 
(a.addr2 <> b.addr2) AND 
(a.city <> b.city) AND 
(a.state <> b.state) AND 
(a.zip <> b.zip)

ORDER BY b.timec DESC
```

*Returns 2 Records.*

I'm trying to do a UNION to have these 2 queries return 1 result set.

**Attempted UNION**:

```
SELECT        
a.memno, 
a.name, 
a.addr1, 
a.addr2, 
a.city, 
a.state, 
a.zip, 
a.sex, 
a.lname, 
a.ssan, 
b.addr1 AS old_addr1, 
b.addr2 AS old_addr2, 
b.city AS old_city, 
b.state AS old_state, 
b.zip AS old_zip

FROM            LIB1.TABLE1 a, LIB2.TABLE2 b

WHERE        (a.memno = b.memno) AND 

(b.groupid = 'P2') AND 
(b.type = 'B') AND 
(b.datec = 20131203) AND 
(a.addr1 <> b.addr1) AND 
(a.addr2 <> b.addr2) AND 
(a.city <> b.city) AND 
(a.state <> b.state) AND 
(a.zip <> b.zip)

UNION

SELECT        
a.memno, 
a.name, 
a.addr1, 
a.addr2, 
a.city, 
a.state, 
a.zip, 
a.sex, 
a.lname, 
a.ssan, 
b.addr1 AS old_addr1, 
b.addr2 AS old_addr2, 
b.city AS old_city, 
b.state AS old_state, 
b.zip AS old_zip

FROM            LIB2.TABLE1 a, LIB2.TABLE2 b

WHERE        (a.memno = b.memno) AND 
(b.groupid = 'N2') AND 
(b.type = 'B') AND 
(b.datec = 20131203) AND 
(a.addr1 <> b.addr1) AND 
(a.addr2 <> b.addr2) AND 
(a.city <> b.city) AND 
(a.state <> b.state) AND 
(a.zip <> b.zip)

ORDER BY timec DESC
```

This gives me:

**Error in WHERE clause near 'DESC'.
Unable to parse query text.**

Followed by:

**SQL Execution Error.**

**Executed SQL Statement: SELECT        a.memno, a.name, a.addr1, a.addr2, a.city, a.state, a.zip, a.sex, a.lname, a.ssan, b.addr1 AS old_addr1, b.addr2 AS old_addr2, b.city AS old_city, 
                             b.state AS old_state, b.zip AS old_zip
    FROM            LIB1.TABLE1 a, LIB2.TABLE2 b
    WHERE        (a.mem...**

**Error Source: CWBODB.DLL**

**Error Message: ERROR [42000][IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver][DB2 for i5/OS]SQL0199 - Keyword DESC not expected. Valid tokens: FOR SKIP WTIH FETCH ORDER UNION EXCEPT OPTIMIZE.**

**EDIT:**

*Bangs Head* Can't believe I missed that I had 'desc' at the end of first query still. After getting rid of the 'desc' at the end of the first query, I now get the same error, but with **Message: Column TIMEC cannot be qualified.**

**EDIT2:**

Message: ORDER BY column TIMEC or expression not in result table.

Comment: You've got `desc` twice in your query, once on line 3, once on line 8. Are you aware of that? The error is about the first one, not the second one.

Comment: Format your queries so they're easier to read -- ex: put each select field on it's own line -- which will help in general, and especially with UNIONS when you need to be extra careful with field numbers and field ordering.

Comment: I edited for query formatting. Better?

Answer (score 3):

First query of the union, you left `desc` at the end of the last line:

```
WHERE a.memno [...snip...] <> b.zipc desc  
                                     ^^^^
```

... which is exactly what the error message said. just because you can see a (valid) `DESC` at the end of the query, doesn't mean there can't be a `desc` somewhere else... This is especially true when your query is a couple miles wide.

Comment: Yea, guess I'm pretty blind to have missed that (and VS2012 doesn't work well in non-full-screen set-up)... Now I'm getting "Column TIMEC cannot be qualified".

Comment: so is there a `timec` column in your `b` table?

Comment: remember that the order by at the END of a union'ed query applies to the ENTIRE union result set by default. there won't be `b.timec` or `a.timec`. There'll just be `timec`.

Comment: I think I get what you're saying. So how do I get around this issue, since there is not an `a.timec` column for the `UNION` to use in the `ORDER BY`?

Comment: Now I receive `ORDER BY column TIMEC or expression not in result table.` Updating posted query now.

Answer (score 0):

In adition to the rogue `DESC` in your first `WHERE` clause, `ORDER BY` is applied to the resulting union (which does not have a `timec` column), not the source datasets.

You can either union the two queries as subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT a.memno, a.name, 
            a.addr1, a.addr2, a.city, a.state, a.zip, a.sex, a.lname, a.ssan, 
            b.addr1 as old_addr1, b.addr2 as old_addr2, b.city as old_city, b.state as old_state, b.zip as old_zip 
    FROM LIB1.TABLE1 a, LIB1.TABLE2 b 
    WHERE a.memno = b.memno 
      and b.groupid = 'P2' 
      and b.type = 'B' 
      and b.datec =  20131205 
      AND a.addr1 <> b.addr1 
      AND a.addr2 <> b.addr2 
      AND a.city <> b.city 
      AND a.state <> b.state 
      AND a.zip <> b.zipc 
    ORDER BY b.timec desc  
    ) A
UNION
SELECT * FROM    
    (
    SELECT a.memno, a.name, 
           a.addr1, a.addr2, a.city, a.state, a.zip, a.sex, a.lname, a.ssan, 
           b.addr1 as old_addr1, b.addr2 as old_addr2, b.city as old_city, b.state as old_state, b.zip as old_zip 
    FROM LIB2.TABLE1 a, LIB2.TABLE2 b 
    WHERE a.memno = b.memno 
      and b.groupid = 'N2' 
      and b.type = 'B' 
      and b.datec = 20131205 
      AND a.addr1 <> b.addr1 
      AND a.addr2 <> b.addr2 
      AND a.city <> b.city 
      AND a.state <> b.state 
      AND a.zip <> b.zip 
    ORDER BY b.timec desc
    ) B
```

Comment: Each query is essentially grabbing the same data fields, but from 2 different  AS400 Libraries with 2 different tables. I have designated these in original post in my first query as `LIB1.TABLE1, LIB1.TABLE2` and in my second query as `LIB2.TABLE1, LIB2.TABLE2`.

Comment: @AnalyticLunatic Didn't catch the different tables.  I'll remove the second option.

Comment: @D Stanley, new issue now. I've EDITED.

Comment: You either need to `order by` in the parts by making them subqueries or add `timec` to your output columns.  I've edited my answer.